# Getting "Search is currently not available." for search results in TYPO3 with ext:solr

Tags: solr, typo3

When I call the solr search result page in the TYPO3 frontend I get the message `Search is currently not available.`

Going further into this, I can see the following response of the call:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "df":"_text_",
      "hl":"true",
      "echoParams":"all",
      "fl":"*,score",
      "hl.fragsize":"200",
      "fq":["siteHash:\"91639e3e14a9fde08edca3fef7846eefc22e0f3a\"",
        "{!typo3access}-2,0,1,2"],
      "spellcheck.maxCollationTries":"1",
      "hl.simple.pre":"<span class=\"results-highlight\">",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "hl.useFastVectorHighlighter":"true",
      "qf":"content^40.0 title^5.0 keywords^2.0 tagsH1^5.0 tagsH2H3^3.0 tagsH4H5H6^2.0 tagsInline description^4.0 abstract subtitle navtitle author",
      "hl.fl":"content",
      "wt":"json",
      "hl.tag.pre":"<span class=\"results-highlight\">",
      "q.alt":"*:*",
      "json.nl":"flat",
      "start":"0",
      "hl.tag.post":"</span>",
      "rows":"10",
      "facet.limit":"100",
      "json.facet":"{\"type\":{\"type\":\"terms\",\"field\":\"type_stringS\",\"limit\":100,\"mincount\":1},\"section\":{\"type\":\"terms\",\"field\":\"section_intS\",\"limit\":100,\"mincount\":1}}",
      "q":"",
      "hl.simple.post":"</span>",
      "omitHeader":"false",
      "spellcheck":"true",
      "facet.mincount":"1",
      "facet":"true",
      "facet.sort":"count",
      "debugQuery":"true",
      "spellcheck.collate":"true"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"invalid query parser 'typo3access' for query '{!typo3access}-2,0,1,2'",
    "code":400}}
```

As far as I understand the error message, this is according to the TYPO3 access rights.
The indexing is working without problems.

For the setup of the solr server I have used the script `bin/install_solr_service.sh` which is shipped with solr.

Did I miss something to configure?

I use:

- TYPO3 9.5.10
- ext:solr: 10.0.1
- solr: 8.5.1

Comment: Am not 100% sure but maybe: Did you include the extension in your main root template includes? (list view > main template > edit > includes). If not , sry not to help :)

Comment: @Rustyjim Yes, I did. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem myself. I used the default configuration for creating the cores.

But, like stated in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/10.0/en-us/GettingStarted/Solr.html#deployment-of-ext-solr-configuration-into-apache-solr) :-), you have to create the core using the correct configset which is delivered with the extension:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=core_de&configSet=ext_solr_10_0_0&schema=german/schema.xml&dataDir=../../data/german"
```

By using this command, the search works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the typo3-solr-filter?

Comment: I have just installed ext:solr itself. Do I need `typo3-solr-filter` and where do I get it?